# Standard Hydrogen Electrode

Tags: electrochemistry

Could someone, please, explain to me how the standard 
Hydrogen Electrode works and how it is used to measure electrode potentials? Also, why does it have a potential value of zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **SHE** (Standard Hydrogen Electrode) is a standard equipment for measuring the ***relative electrode potential***, as the process of measuring the actual potential is quite difficult. It consists of a platinum foil dipped in 1.0M $\ce{HCl}$ in the presence of $\ce{H2}$ gas at 1 bar of pressure.

Now when the SHE is connected to another half-cell, either oxidation or reduction may occur in the SHE.

Suppose we have to find the electrode potential of a half cell represented by "A" Now, on setting up the cell and connecting a voltmeter we get the standard potential(E<sub>standard</sub>) of the cell i.e.
**E<sub>standard</sub> = E<sub>A</sub> - E<sub>H<sub>2</sub></sub>**
Now as our our aim is to just find E<sub>A</sub>, we take E<sub>H<sub>2</sub></sub> to be equal to 0
Therefore,
**E<sub>standard</sub> = E<sub>A</sub> - 0**
or,
**E<sub>standard</sub> = E<sub>A</sub>**

The value of E<sub>standard</sub> is taken from the voltmeter.
It should be noted that the electrode potential calculated using this method is **relative**(to the electrode potential of hydrogen). It isn't the absolute value. 
Also, the potential for the SHE is ***taken to be 0*** for the simplification of the process.

Comment: The SHE also has hydrogen gas in it so that either half reaction can occur: $$\ce{2H+ +2 e- -> H2}$$ $$\ce{H2 -> 2H+ + 2e-}$$