# Single electrode potential measurement

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, equilibrium, reduction-potential

My textbook says that in a galvanic cell, it's not possible to measure single electrode potential independently. Instead, a Standard Hydrogen Electrode is used as the system is under equilibrium. Can someone explain this concept more clearly?

Comment: What is unclear there? Closed circuit is needed, you can't have that with only one electrode in solution.

Comment: But what does  the system being in equilibrium have to do with it? Sorry if the question is trivial, just learning these stuff!

Comment: Probably that nothing happens so it's sort of "equilibrium".

Comment: Equilibrium means that the chemical potential has to be the same for the two side of the cell. One thing cannot be in equilibrium, as it makes no sense, it needs another system to be equilibrium with - which can act as a reference electrode

Comment: @Greg Can't the escaping of metal ions from electrode into electrolyte and the deposition of metal on the electrode be considered for equilibrium?

Comment: @GauthamShankar Why would it be?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28534/standard-hydrogen-electrode

Comment: Through a more complicated technique, it **is** possible to determine an absolute reduction potential for a single electrode. I don't really understand why this isn't more well-known and why the absolute values aren't given in textbooks.

Answer (score 4):

Electrodes transport electrons produced from one half-cell to another, thus producing an electric charge. You need to have a reference value to compare it to in order to obtain the *relative potential*. Relative to the Standard Hydrogen Electrode (SHE), that is.

The SHE has a potential that is set arbitrarily to zero giving you a basis with which to compare the potentials from the electrode you're testing.

For further reading, I feel [this article on the Standard Hydrogen electrode](https://www.ck12.org/chemistry/Standard-Hydrogen-Electrode/lesson/Standard-Hydrogen-Electrode-CHEM/) is pretty descriptive.

Answer (score -1):

Potential is a relative measurement. You will need to set a reference for measuring any potential.

As in this case, Hydrogen electrode is set as the reference.

All other potentials are measured against Standard Hydrogen electrode to get their potentials under *standard conditions*.